# Graspit installation package for Hydro?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, grasping, packages, roshydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been trying to install Graspit simulator for some research work and got my Ros Hydro distro installed yesterday on ubuntu Precise. Could you please tell me if there is any way to install the simulator for ros hydro? I saw a post

http://answers.ros.org/question/10455/grasping-force-closure-node/

that gives me some idea about getting graspit in the diamondback ROS distro and found out ros packages for graspit have no mention of hydro. Am I missing something ?Any suggestions please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122576/graspit-installation-package-for-hydro?/) by [Luminosity](https://answers.ros.org/users/11251/luminosity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you still want to install graspit_simulator on Hydro, you should update all the packages of the stack to use catkin instead of rosbuild.
I've done that and could send you the updated files, but I don't know:

- If everything really works
- How to use the different services provided by the grapit_ros_planning node
- If I will keep using them; so don't expect any support at all
- If there's any official support at all either...

I've also made some packages for Ubuntu 12.04 32bits, if you want to do a system wide installation.

Edit: The comments are not that appropriate to post links so...

It's great to see the project is still maintained!

The source stack is here: http://pkgs.redox.ws/src/deb/ros/graspit_simulator_20140224.tar.gz

The Ubuntu 12.04 32bits packages I've made are here (small warning, they just work; but they're not really clean/well packaged)

- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-graspit_20140224-1_i386.deb
- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-graspit-ros-planning_20140224-1_i386.deb
- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-graspit-ros-planning-msgs_20140224-1_i386.deb
- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-graspit-dbase-tasks_20140224-1_i386.deb
- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-dbase-grasp-planner_20140224-1_i386.deb

Dependencies:

- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-household-objects-database_20140224-1_i386.deb
- http://pkgs.redox.ws/deb/ros/ros-hydro-sql-database_20140224-1_i386.deb

---

Originally posted by [RedoXyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/12196/redoxyde/) with karma: 66 on 2014-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonWeisz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5120/jonweisz/) on 2014-02-25**:
Hello,
I'm one of the developers of GraspIt! We've been planning to release a catkinized package as soon as someone has time. If you've already got something, we would love to verify that it works and release it if you're willing to share.

**Comment by [FDamani](https://answers.ros.org/users/18801/fdamani/) on 2014-06-06**:
Hi, have you guys released a package for Hydro yet?

**Comment by [pk](https://answers.ros.org/users/22577/pk/) on 2015-06-05**:
Hi, RedoXyde.,I am new in robotics and for a project I have to use Graspit!. I have ubuntu 12.04 64 bit running. And yes there is no official support for ros hydro. I am using shunk hand and kuka youbot hand. I have saved grasps in text file, using 'save to text option'. Can you tell how to use it?

**Comment by [RedoX](https://answers.ros.org/users/9416/redox/) on 2015-06-05**:
Hi,

Unfortunately for you, I haven't used GraspIt! for over a year (and ROS for over six months) so I can't really help you.

Good luck with your project.

RedoXyde

Edit: Looks like I have two accounts...